# Question re: GraphQL query is unauthorized

Tags: graphql-query

I started receiving "GraphQL Query is Unauthorized" message when I click on the private message link in Facebook. It also occurs when I click on notifications. Is there an easy fix? Thanks in advance for any help.

(I refreshed the page, then logged out and logged back in. I was hoping it would resolve but it is still happening.)